# Pandoc issue with html download

Tags: formatting, header-footer, pandoc, conversion, html

I have a problem with pandoc.
I have a script that converts markdown files into pdfs with pandoc and LaTeX and uses a `.tex` file with the `--include-in-header` option to format the input.

This works like a charm.

I now wanted to do the same with links and the html input to download links from e.g. the Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy to convert them to PDF with pandoc, which should work in theory.
The problem is that it only works when I don't try to include the aforementioned header file. If I don't use it, the website is downloaded and converted to a pdf.
If I include the header file, I get the error message:

```
l.68 <
      !DOCTYPE html>
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on /tmp/tex2pdf.-fe99ca013ef35d41/input.log.
```

even if the header file is totally empty (I thought it might be a problem with the contents of the header file but apparently it is not).

The command that is supposed to do the trick:

```
pandoc -f html -s -t pdf --include-in-header $HEADER_FILE -V geometry:a4paper -V geometry:margin=2cm -V fontsize=11pt --verbose -o $OUTPUT $WEBSITE
```

I can also provide the header file if necessary, but as I said, it doesn't even work if the header file is empty and it does work with the same header file if the input file is a markdown file.
Also the log file in the error-message is not where says it should be, I therefore can't find the logs to look for more specific errors.

Comment: Are you sure this question belong to this site because if it doesn’t work with an empty tex file it looks to a pandoc related question only? IMO, you should consider asking in another site on the SE network, maybe [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)… BTW, next time, please avoid polite formulas in questions, it’s not rude, just to keep the question focussed only on the problem.